# Anchor position is equal to position minus header height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have fixed header. When i click on anchor link, it goes on that position. The problem is that height of my fixed header overlap that position. I want when i go to some anchor point that it's position is = anchor - header height.

**Here is my javascript code:**

```
<script> <!--Anchors-->
$(function() {
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you put your html and css  code

Comment: There is no need for that.

`<a href="#somediv"> Link </a>

<div id="somediv">
... content
</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You can add some margin before the page content

```
#fixed-header{
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    top: 0;
}
body { 
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help me because my header is not on top of the page. There is first home section with `width:100vw` and `height:100vh` and then there is my sticky header.

Comment: @pHenomen well that is why you need to add more code to all of your questions. How is anyone supposed to know that?